Will there be another moderator election in the foreseeable future?
So, I know that there are four moderators, and that one of these moderators were elected in the most recent election. I would I also like to say that I mean absolutely no offence in what I am asking, I am not insulting, criticizing, or telling anyone that they are doing anything wrong.
Even though I am new to InfoSec SE, it is quite clear that only one moderator, not to name names, actually consistently moderates at the moment. I am sure that many of you have also realized that one moderator in particular definitely does their fair share (aka all) of moderating, or in the time that I have witnessed this, at least.
I just think that some members of the community probably moderate a lot more than three of the current moderators- and plus- these certain three moderators have already served for a long time, and might just be sick of moderating by now, which is definitely fair enough if this is the case.
Since it has been many years since the last election, and many things have changed, will there be another moderator election sometime soon? I am asking in a very open and non-accusatory or demanding tone, and I also want to know what the community thinks about another election.
And I am not suggesting or talking about kicking out the three less-active moderators at all- my only thoughts is since the community is growing, and only one moderator consistently moderates currently, maybe there's room for some new extra moderators- and I'm also confident we'd get a lot of candidates.
And a big thankyou to every moderator on this site- we as a community wouldn't be where we are at now without all of you.
Cheers :D

Just want to point out that while currently two mods are more active than the rest, our activity stats disagree a bit with your assumptions, and the ebb and flow of activity does change over time between mods.
So while it's a useful call out for us to check in, it is really just a slightly incorrect assumption based on the limited visibility you may have over mod activity. I wouldn't worry about that though - core data isn't shared outside staff and mods, so you can only go off what you perceive.
One of the additional checks and balances we can fall back on, is that SE check in with us around workload, so if things look too much for the existing mod team, we look at the needs for additional mods, or even replacing mods if there are good reasons for it. I don't think this is the case in this situation, but thank you for the trigger to go and discuss it with the wider mod team and SE.
Oh, and on a mature site like this, we do expect community moderation to be the biggest chunk - a self managed community is the ideal scenario - while the mods take care of the messier stuff.

There have been times when each of us was the most active moderator. I'm not here to run the show; I'm here to make sure the show runs. If it's running without out me, it's a good show.
At the moment when you see one of us quieting down, another will surely step up the activity.

@RoryAlsop and JeffFerland I am replying to both of your answers which, by the way are both very good! Thanks very much for explaining- and again, I really meant no offence to any of you mods- you all rock! Cheers :D
